# Advanced directory switching in bash

Tags: bash

I know a few advanced ways, to change directories. `pushd` and `popd` (directory stack) or `cd -` (change to last directory).

But I am looking for quick way to achieve the following:

Say, I am in a rather deep dir:

```
/this/is/a/very/deep/directory/structure/with\ lot\ of\ nasty/names
```

and I want to switch to

```
/this/is/another/very/deep/directory/structure/with\ lot\ of\ nasty/names
```

Is there a cool/quick/geeky way to do it (without the mouse)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean that the path names are the same, and only one directory name changes ("a" becomes "another")? In that case:

```
cd ${PWD/a/another}
```

will switch to the other directory. `$PWD` holds your current directory, and `${var/foo/bar}` gives you `$var` with the string 'foo' replaced by 'bar'.

Answer (score 3):

What about setting up your `CDPATH` variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ^/a/^/another/
```